# $_FILES undefined index : file

Tags: php, file

```
<?php
    echo $_FILES['file']['error'];
?>

<form action="uploads.php" method = "POST">
    <input  name="file" type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I am getting an `undefined index file` error for this code.

What should I do?

This is just the shortened version of the code that I am trying to implement. In the original code I have used `isset()` function. However in that case I am not getting any output!

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` should be an attribute of `<form>`, not the `<input>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct way is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo $_FILES['file']['error'];
}
?>

<form action="uploads.php" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input  name="file" type="file"><br>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name='submit'/>
</form>
```

You are echoing "`$_FILES['file']['error']`" before form submit. echo input type file value or something after form submission.

Comment: Thanks that helped! Cant believe I was overseeing that mistake each time I was rechecking my code!

Answer (score 3):

```
<form action="uploads.php" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

should help you here, you must use it in form!

Answer (score 1):

use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form

```
  <form action="uploads.php" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    echo $_FILES['file']['error'];
}
?>

<form action="uploads.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"">
    <input  name="file" type="file" /><br>
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```